# Batch-Script - Won't proceed after FOR-Loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I got a Startup-Script which does close and open some services and in the end open a process on the desktop. The name of the desktop icon could be variable, so we used a FOR-Loop there. Anyhow since we added the FOR-Loop it wont close the script. It looks like its hanging in the for Loop, but when i try the for loop in a testcript alone it will close the script after but not in my original script..

```
tasklist |find /i "pxTel.exe" >nul
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
echo [32mStarte Programm Telefon Integration... Alles in Ordnung![0m
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b %HOMEPATH%\Desktop\pxTel*') DO %HOMEPATH%\Desktop\%%G
timeout 3
) else (
echo [32mProgramm Telefon-Integration laeuft bereits... ueberspringe..[0m
)
```

Comment: So - if you add an extra `echo` line after the `for` command lines, does it reach that extra `echo`? If you added a line `echo processing "%%G"` before the `timeout 3` line, does it report the filename being processed?

Comment: change to `dir /b %userprofile%\Desktop\pxTel*') DO %userprofile%\Desktop\%%G`

Comment: What do you mean by startup script? how do you launch the script at startup? Did you configure the script to be executed at windows startup, or executed when opening a cmd session?

Comment: I tested it and it isn't reaching the echo between FOR and timeout 3 sadly. Neither works the echo processing %%G command there. It starts my Process but wont proceed then.

Comment: Change to %userprofile% didnt bring any effect. With startup Script i mean I configured it in the schedule task to start when i log in with my user account. But that souldnt have to do with it since I'm able to reproduce the error on a second script without schedule task..right?

Comment: using `start %HOMEPATH\Desktop\%%G%` also doesn't work?

Comment: Wow that worked =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be happening due to a large number of reasons.

It is actually happening to me even: the command `dir /b %HOMEPATH%\Desktop\*` does not seem to return on my machine right now.  That's because my `%HOMEPATH%` variable is set to `\`, so the command expands to `dir /b \\Desktop\*`, and there is no machine called `Desktop`, so it appears to hang while timing out.

You might ask, how come my `%HOMEPATH%` is set to `\` ?  Well, that's because my `%HOMEDRIVE%` is set to `Y:`, a network share, so `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` expands to `Y:\` which is the intention.

So, what do we learn from this?

Either always use `%HOMEPATH%` together with `%HOMEDRIVE%`, or just use `%USERPROFILE%` instead.

Also, always enclose paths in double quotes, otherwise the spaces will wreak havoc.